# How document training and result of tensorflow object detection api?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection-api

When I run some trainings with the Tensorflow Object Detection API, how can I document (save) the

- batch size
- number of epochs/steps
- duration per step
- model (ssd, faster r-cnn, ...)
- backbone
- pretrained (yes/no)
- callback functions
- loss-graphs
- (Mean) Average Precision

Is there some  tool to do this automatically or do I need to program it myself?

I have heard of Data Version Control or Apache Airflow, but I look for something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

For model training metadata like batch size, model type and loss function, it's usually recorded in [json](https://github.com/victoresque/pytorch-template#config-file-format) or yaml format.

For auto logging you can take a look at [MLFlow for Tensorflow](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tensorflow.html). There is also an [official example](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/tree/master/examples/tensorflow).